# Printing multiple pages not working in React-to-Print

Tags: reactjs

we are loading 100 records in the grid initially, after that when we scroll down , loading another set of data.
But when we try to print the page its loading just 100 records in the print preview screen, we are  using react-to-print, functional component.

```
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
  });
```

we want load all the data available in the List, please help.

Answer (score 1):

For me [this solution](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/issues/54#issuecomment-428201934) worked, setting height for body and html to initial for print.

```
@media print { html, body { height: initial !important; overflow: initial !important; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a similar problem and this [answer](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/issues/213#issuecomment-588896435) from github helped me.

You have to surround your render with a div of styling `overflow: scroll` and also remove overflow styling, maximum height and any other view limiting styling from the surrounded element's "stylings" like the example below.

**Disclaimer**: *I used MUI in some instances.*

```
render() {
 <div sx={{ overflow: "scroll" }}>
  {
   sampleIterable.map((x,n) => {
   ...
   })
  }
 </div>
}
```